# Async function returns undefined (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I'm trying to use global variable inside one of my async function.

```
export const getSubscriptions = async () => {
    return await axios
    .get("url.com")
    .then(response => response.data)
};

  async created() {
    this.subscriptions = await getSubscriptions()
      console.log(this.subscriptions); //returns correct values
    this.filteredItems()
  },
```

filteredItems function in methods :

```
async filteredItems () {
     console.log(this.subscriptions); // returns undefined
},
```

Any idea?

Comment: It would be impossible in normal circumstances to get a different result in the method since it's just logging the same property as in `created`.  You sure you're not calling the method from somewhere else, like maybe the template?

Comment: Can you create a snippet reproducing the problem?